# cannot import name 'BlobServiceClient' even if 'Azure-blob-Storage' latest version azure-storage-blob==12.9.0 is installed

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-notebooks

I am trying to execute a script in `'Azure Notebooks'` to upload blob to `Azure Data lake Gen 2` using `'Azure-storage-blob'`, but couldn't as I am unable to `import 'BlobServiceClient'`. I have latest version of `'Azure-storage-blob' - 12.9.0` installed. But still facing issue in importing `'BlobServiceClient'`

Below is the code

```
import azure.storage.blob
from azure.storage.blob import blockblobservice
import os, uuid
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__
```

Below is the error

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-278-283cd1817c6e> in <module>
      7 from azure.storage.blob import blockblobservice
      8 import os, uuid
----> 9 from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__
     10 
     11 try:

ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobServiceClient'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this

**1.**  Uninstall azure-storage-blob using: pip uninstall azure-storage-blob.

**2.**  Reinstall azure-storage-blob using: pip install azure-storage-blob.

And from your code `from azure.storage.blob import blockblobservice` you are trying to  import `blockblobservice` . In newer versions of `azure-storage-blob` the import `BlockBlobService` has been renamed to `BlobServiceClient`.

I tried with this import statement

**`from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__`**

OUTPUT:

[image]

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python#set-up-the-app-framework)

Comment: Good solution. It worked for me when I did uninstall and reinstall.